# Hibernate: How to define map values column name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class with map inside. It is mapped with use of join table.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Sources")
@Lazy(false)
public class Sources {      
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )  
    @JoinTable( name = "sources_lists", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "list_id" ) )
@MapKeyColumn( name = "source_id" )
public Map<Integer, Source> getSources() { return sources; }
public void setSources( Map<Integer, Source> sourcesList ) { this.adSources = adSourcesList; }
private Map<Integer, Source> sources;

@Override
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column( name="id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
public Integer getId() { return super.getId(); }
}
```

I receive the following exception: "Unknown column 'sources0_.sources' in 'field list'".
When I change 'list_id' column name to the 'sources' things work, but I can't do this in production.

Tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `sources` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) );

CREATE TABLE `source` (
`DTYPE` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`className` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `sources_lists` (
list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `FK54DCBD0B4307D0FC` (`source_id`),
KEY `FK54DCBD0B575FBECF` (`list_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK54DCBD0B4307D0FC` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK54DCBD0B575FBECF` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) REFERENCES `sources` (`id`));
```

Comment: Did you mean to capitalize this `@Table(name = "Sources")`. It looks like sources should be lowercase. `@Table(name = "sources")`

Comment: I tried both lower and upper case. As I wrote, Hibernate stops to complain when I'm changing column name in DB from 'list_id' to 'sources., So the problem is with Sources.getSources() method. It looks like Hibernate ignores @JoinColumn=(name="list_id") annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue was not with column, but with somethings else: I want to map Source objects by its id and Hibernate assumes that there are 3 columns in join table: parent object id (Sources class, list_id column), object id (Source class, source_id column) and a separate column for map key. I'll open other question to ask what is the way to map object in Hibernate by its id.